# Make a transaction inside aspect

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aspectj

I have an aspect with the method, annotated by @Around, where there are the following lines:

```
@Around("@annotation(CustomAnnotation)")
public void handle(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    MethodSignature ms = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    CustomAnnotation m = ms.getMethod().getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
    Processor processor = appContext.getBean(m.value());
    Object argument = joinPoint.getArgs()[0]; 

    processor.preProcess(argument);
    joinPoint.proceed();
    processor.postProcess(argument);
}
```

Method to be interrupted by Aspect:

```
@CustomAnnotation(value = "CreateProcessor")
public void create(User user) {
    createOrUpdate(user); //in this method user in "Users" is created or updated
}
```

Processor.preProcess() is empty.

Processor.postProcess():

```
@Override
public void postProcess(Object obj) {
    //add obj to "Objects" table in DB
}
```

All these methods (preProcess, postProcess, proceed) interact with separate database tables. So I want to make a transaction with these 3 method calls, i.e. when one of them isn't executed successfully, the changes made by the previous ones should be reverted. How can I achieve my goal?

Upd.
I have tried the next steps:

Added the following rows to my context file:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

And added @Transactional annotation on my handle() method.

To check if the rollback is performed, I added exception throwing:

```
@Override
public void postProcess(Object obj) {
    throw new RuntimeException("TEST");
    //add obj to "Objects" table in DB
}
```

Though exception is thrown and there is no new row in "Objects" table, new row in "Users" appears.

Comment: What happens when you add a @Transactional annotation on the method which in these 3 calls are made? I am assuming you are using spring framework.

Comment: Added this info to the first post.

Comment: Show some more code, please, e.g. the full aspect and not just three statements from an advice (that is the name of the "method" you mention in AOP terms). It would also make sense to show the method called by `proceed()` as well as the other two.

Comment: The root cause seems different from what you have been trying out - Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure. Does creating a simple jdbc connection work out?

Comment: @kriegaex I updated the first post with more information about the methods used.

Comment: @AndyDufresne Changed the way of checking if the transaction is rollbacked.